# Print Server Force Page Orientation, Paper Size, etc

Tags: windows, printing, network-printer, print-server

We have a naive application that prints without having configurable options for page orientation, paper size, etc. The solution has been to create multiple queues for each set of configuration options, so that printing landscape is a different "printer" from printing portrait, etc.

We do this using EasySpooler, which we'd like to stop using if there's a good (free) alternative, since it has more power than we need, and its interface and configuration is not as easy as we'd like.

Can Windows queues have these settings forced or defaulted on a queue? If not, is there some other application or daemon that we can run to get this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can do this natively with Windows Server by setting the default Printer Preferences for a print queue that is hosted on a print server.

Start Print Management as a user with with sufficient privileges to change the print queue settings on print server. Connect to your print server, right click the printer in question under Printers and select Set Printing Defaults. You can then set the default Printer Preferences for that print queue.